# Выравнивание структур Си

Tags: c

Имею структуру, которую хочу считать за одно применение fread. Если я не отключаю выравнивание с помощью `#pragma pack(pop)`  считываются некорректные данные, но, насколько я понял, отключение выравнивания является плохой практикой. Есть ли какая-то альтернатива?
Сама структура:

```
typedef struct BITMAPINFOHEADER
{
    DWORD biSize; // Размер структуры
    LONG biWidth; // Ширина изображения в пикселах.
    LONG biHeight; // Высота изображения в пикселах.
    WORD biPlanes; // Количество плоскостей. Равно 1 при кол-ве цветов >=256.
    WORD biBitCount; // Глубина цвета в битах на пиксель.
    DWORD biCompression; // Тип сжатия.
    DWORD biSizeImage; // Размер изображения в байтах.
    LONG biXPelsPerMeter; // Горизонтальное разрешениe.
    LONG biYPelsPerMeter; // Вертикальное разрешениe.
    DWORD biClrUsed; // Количество используемых цветов кодовой таблицы, 0 == max.
    DWORD biClrImportant; // Количество используемых (выжных) цветов кодовой таблицы. 0 == max.
} BMI;
```

Спасибо!

Comment: А пишете вы? Тогда писать (fwrite) с тем же выравниванием.

Comment: Можно поля структуры местами менять. Например `char int short char` можно поменять на `char char short int` и структура будет выровнена.

Comment: @Harry, в каком смысле? Мне просто нужно изначально заполнить элементы структуры из файла с расширением BMP, потом  записывать никуда не нужно

Comment: @ПавелЕриков, мне нужно заполнить именно в том порядке, который дан изначально

Comment: @GlebKamisaraw приведите пример структуры

Comment: @ПавелЕриков, отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Отключите выравнивание только для этой структуры. Это нормальная практика.

Comment: Эта структура уже объявлена с правильным выравниванием в `wingdi.h`